# Grid in a Edit Form (backend) : Ajax is not working

Tags: grid, forms, grid-serlization

I have included a product grid in edit form tab. ( same edit category does ), however when I search the ajax loader doesn't stop and I'm redirected to the main tab.

I can post part of code if needed but I would only if required ( many files involved )

**UPDATE**:

it looks like the problem is that the param `$url` passed to the function `reload` (grid.js) doesn't contains `?isAjax=true`

Comment: Let's debug. Do you have `getGridUrl()` method inside of your `Edit/Tab/[Tabname].php` and if yes then what is the first parameter of `getUrl()` method there?

Comment: I have solved, studying magento edit form ( like the product one that contains the related products).
Right now I have changed all code so I don't know exactly where the issue was however I would point my finger at the `getGridUrl()` and some parameters passed to `addTab()`, like 'class' => 'ajax'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite some tutorials explaining how to add a custom admin grids. Unfortunately some of them are missing the fact that sorting and filtering functionality require additional controller action.

This action is specified by `getGridUrl()` method of your grid class. The pitfall is that this method is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` so if you forget to override it you may notice it until you try to sort or filter your grid. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getGridUrl()` returns `$this->getCurrentUrl()` which doesn't make much sense. So obvious move would be to override it with something like this:

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
```

The simple controller action that will just render a layout will wrap things up:

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: yes I have, in both, the main grid and in the grid contained in the edit form tab

Comment: please see my edit.